# How to get the Dragon Track past the tutorial to a race? 

Tags: dragonvale

My race track has only the tutorial feature. I indeed cannot race in the dragon track. I'm looking for help.

Comment: Might want to edit it and ask "How do I get my race track out of the tutorial?" or something along the lines of that.

Comment: Are you clicking on the race flags next to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Just finish the tutorial. The race track will operate normally after you complete the tutorial fully.

Comment: Hey Ben, I did. Maybe 10 times now. o.O

Comment: @SunnyBrown You've got some bug then, I've never had a problem with the race...latest version and all that?

Comment: Yes, latest version and all that. Gotta love the bugs. Sigh. Thank you.

Comment: _slaps bug with swatter_ Smackery smackity smack! **SLAP THAT THANG!**