# Can't race on the Dragon Track

Tags: dragonvale, android

I can't race in the dragon track for Dragonvale, not even for the tutorial. I don't know if the problem is my android, or if the problem is the app itself. My phone is not jailbroken, and I really want to try out the dragon track. Why can't I race?

Comment: Does http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84896/how-to-get-the-dragon-track-past-the-tutorial-to-a-race answer your question?

Comment: The solution to most problems with Dragonvale is to quit the game and re-load it.  If you can't figure out how to quit the game completely, try turning your phone off and back on.

Comment: Can you describe a little more the exact behavior you are seeing?  When you tap on the track, what happens?  As agent86 suggests, power cycling your device may help.  If you link your park with Facebook, you might try it there too and see if the problem persists.

Comment: To _bump up_ your question, try taking a screenshot of it, explaining the problem a little more, etc., if you can. If not, look it up on the Dragonvale Wiki, might answer your question.